# Let $s_n\le M$ be a sequence where $n\in \mathbb N$. Sequence converges to $L$. Prove that $L\le M$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My attempt: Let $L=M+1$. If $ -1<s_n -L<1$ then $M<s_n<M+2$ which is a contradiction. Thus $L$ should be $\leq M$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong, since you cannot assume that $L=M+1$.

Suppose that $L>M$. Let $\varepsilon=L-M$. Then, if $n$ is large enough, you have $\lvert L-s_n\rvert<\varepsilon=L-M$. In particular, $L-s_n<L-M$, which is equivalent to $s_n>M$. But we are assuming that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):s_n\leqslant M$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it is obvious. Suppose $L>M$, take an open neighbourhood of $L$ not containing $M$. All but finitely many terms of the sequence lie in this neighborhood, which is a contradiction. Now, you can easily write it mathematically.